# Tensorflow tensor cannot be converted to numpy

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to convert `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor` to NumPy.

TensorFlow version is `2.4.1`

I tried to search some methods, but they did not work.

```
x = tf.reshape(tf.io.decode_raw(x, tf.float64), (3, 4096))
x = x.numpy()
```

Above results in `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`  (I added `tf.executing_eagerly()` explicitly, but did not work)

I tried `x = x.eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())`, but this below error occurred.

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'args_0' with dtype string
```

Please tell me good idea.

Comment: If you can please show what's contained in the original data `x` or at least a minimal reproducible subset of it so we can help, that'd be great!

Comment: I cannot show detail , but x is derived from  tf.io.parse_single_example object.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample working code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
x=[["1"],["23"]]
x = tf.reshape(tf.io.decode_raw(tf.constant(x), tf.uint8, fixed_length=4), (2,4))
x = x.numpy()
x
```

**Output**

```
array([[49,  0,  0,  0],
       [50, 51,  0,  0]], dtype=uint8)
```